# exchange data between two web services using spring boot and docker-compose

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, web-services, docker-compose

For example i have one object stored on the first webservice that can be accessed by "http://localhost:5000/articles/1"
`{"id":"1","name":"article1","description":"Desc1","partsId": 2}`

and another webservice that can be accesed by "http://localhost:80/api/parts2" stores parts object 
`{"id": 2,"manufacturer": "manufacture", "name": "name", "price": "228", "type": "type"}`
my docker-compose.yml:

```
`version: '3.7'
services:
    articles-service:
        container_name: articles-service
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
        volumes:
        - .:/service
        networks:
            - ws_bridge
    computer-parts:
        build: ./comp_parts
        command: python app.py
        ports:
            - "80:5000"
        volumes:
        - .:/service
        container_name: external
        networks:
            - ws_bridge
networks:
    ws_bridge:`
```

I want to be able to get the Part object by its id
The code that i wrote:

```
@GetMapping("/parts/{id}")
public PcPart getPartFromOtherService(@PathVariable String id) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<PcPart[]> response =
            restTemplate.getForEntity(
                    "http://external:80/api/parts/" + id, // The problem lies here in the url
                    PcPart[].class);
    PcPart[] parts = response.getBody();
    return parts[0];
}
```

What url should i use or how to connect them to be able to retrieve the data (changing external to localhost in the url doesn't help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use your Service-name(computer-parts:5000/api/parts) 
You'll find your data.

In docker-compose service name is used as a host for that container.

Comment: Service name acts as dns entries in docker-compose but it's still recommended to use these redirection URLs as environment variables. Makes life easier to modify. Once you've setup your env you can simply load http://${COMPUTER-SERVICE}:${PORT}/<endpoint>

Answer (score 0):

You might try setting the `hostname` property in your `docker-compose.yml` for each service.

```
`version: '3.7'
services:
    articles-service:
        container_name: articles-service
        hostname: articles
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
        volumes:
        - .:/service
        networks:
            - ws_bridge
    computer-parts:
        build: ./comp_parts
        hostname: computer
        command: python app.py
        ports:
            - "80:5000"
        volumes:
        - .:/service
        container_name: external
        networks:
            - ws_bridge
networks:
    ws_bridge:`
```

Since Docker-Compose helps manage the network, I believe you can do something like `http://computer:5000`.  The hostname will resolve it to pointing to the appropriate internal Docker IP for that service.  Make sure you use the internal facing port not the external facing port.  I'm assuming in all this you want to communicate or call APIs between services.  If you're outside Docker running local Java code, that's different.

Comment: Hello, I've updated the docker-compose file and url as you said and I'm getting this error I/O error on GET request for \"http://computer:5000/api/parts/1\": parts; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: parts, maybe it's possible to somehow give the container host ip and access through it?

Comment: Hmm, maybe try `docker inspect articles-service` and `docker inspect external`.  That should give you details on the internal IP addresses being used by Docker.  You could also do `docker network ls` and then `docker network inspect networknamehere`.  That's actually probably easier to read.

Comment: docker network inspect shop_ws_bridge gave me external container ipv4 address, however when I tried to getEntity with rest template using this url "http://172.19.0.3:5000/api/parts/1"  it gave this error `"404 : [{\"timestamp\":\"2020-04-30T19:56:27.822+0000\",\"status\":404,\"error\":\"Not Found\",\"message\":\"No message available\",\"path\":\"/api/parts/1\"}]"`

Comment: Hmm sorry, I'm out of ideas.  My last thought would be perhaps try getting into the container itself and running ping/curl commands on the commandline on the various IPs, hostnames, and ports to check what works and what doesn't.  That might help you then enter the appropriate information in Java to make the request.  I would also double-check to make sure the service works within the container itself on localhost to confirm your apps are running and not down or something.